Test libdl failed when cross-compile qt5.15.14 for aarch64-linux with gcc9 and glibc2.31
1. I'm now trying to cross-compile Qt5.15.14 for runing on arm64 board.

Host: x86_64 linux Ubuntu 22.04
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
ToolChain: aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc 9.2 ,downloaded from ARM's website
Sysroot: ubuntu 20.04 base-image, with libc6-dev installed
Glibc of ToolChain: 2.30
Glibc of Sysroot: 2.31

I aimed to enable "elgfs" , but the "configure" script gave the error information:
ERROR: Feature 'dlopen' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'config.unix && libs.libdl' failed.

ERROR: Feature 'egl' was enabled, but the pre-condition '(features.opengl || features.openvg) && (features.angle || libs.egl) && (features.dlopen || !config.unix || config.integrity)' failed.

ERROR: Feature 'eglfs' was enabled, but the pre-condition '!config.android && !config.darwin && !config.win32 && !config.wasm && features.egl' failed.

I check the pre-condition and I believe that if the libs.libdl test passes , the other tests will pass too.

2. I copy the test source file from config.tests/libdl/main.cpp, which content is
/* Generated by configure */
#include <dlfcn.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void)argc; (void)argv;
    /* BEGIN TEST: */
    dlclose(dlopen(0, 0));
    dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, 0);
    dlerror();
    /* END TEST */
    return 0;
}

And do some tests:
Test1 Cross compile on Host without sysroot
$ARMCC -o a.out  main.cpp -L${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/libc/usr/lib64/ -ldl -fPIC

a.out was generated. and ldd
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x000000550183e000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000005501852000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000005501a37000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000005501ae2000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000005501b06000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000005500000000)


Test2 Compile on Target using qemu
g++ -o a.out  main.cpp -ldl -fPIC

a.out was generated. and ldd gives
    libdl.so.2 (0x000000550184a000)
    libc.so.6 (0x000000550185e000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000005500000000)

Test3 Cross compile on Host with sysroot
$ARMCC -o a.o  main.cpp -ldl -fPIC -Wl,-rpath-link,${SYSROOT}/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -I=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -L=/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --sysroot=${SYSROOT} --verbose

log:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../libexec/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-none-linux-gnu
Configured with: /tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm2--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-linux-gnu/build/src/gcc/configure --target=aarch64-none-linux-gnu --prefix= --with-sysroot=/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/libc --with-build-sysroot=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm2--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-linux-gnu/build/build-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/install//aarch64-none-linux-gnu/libc --with-bugurl=https://bugs.linaro.org/ --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-shared --disable-libssp --disable-libmudflap --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-gmp=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm2--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-linux-gnu/build/build-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/host-tools --with-mpfr=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm2--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-linux-gnu/build/build-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/host-tools --with-mpc=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm2--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-linux-gnu/build/build-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/host-tools --with-isl=/tmp/dgboter/bbs/rhev-vm2--rhe6x86_64/buildbot/rhe6x86_64--aarch64-none-linux-gnu/build/build-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/host-tools --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --with-pkgversion='GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 9.2-2019.12 (arm-9.10)'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.2.1 20191025 (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 9.2-2019.12 (arm-9.10)) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'a.o' '-fPIC' '-I' '=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu' '-L=/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mlittle-endian' '-mabi=lp64'
 /home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../libexec/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/cc1plus -quiet -v -I =/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -iprefix /home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/ -isysroot /home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu/ -D_GNU_SOURCE main.cpp -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -mlittle-endian -mabi=lp64 -auxbase main -version -fPIC -o /tmp/ccm4e77A.s
GNU C++14 (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 9.2-2019.12 (arm-9.10)) version 9.2.1 20191025 (aarch64-none-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 3.1.6, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.15-1-g835ea3a-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.2.1"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.2.1/aarch64-none-linux-gnu"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.2.1/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu//usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu
 /home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.2.1
 /home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.2.1/aarch64-none-linux-gnu
 /home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.2.1/backward
 /home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/include
 /home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/include-fixed
 /home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/include
 /home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu/usr/local/include
 /home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu/usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 9.2-2019.12 (arm-9.10)) version 9.2.1 20191025 (aarch64-none-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 3.1.6, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.15-1-g835ea3a-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 2c1b06ae38fc097703f75fa12d3b7029
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'a.o' '-fPIC' '-I' '=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu' '-L=/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mlittle-endian' '-mabi=lp64'
 /home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/as -v -I =/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -EL -mabi=lp64 -o /tmp/ccVgrV4P.o /tmp/ccm4e77A.s
GNU assembler version 2.33.1 (aarch64-none-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 9.2-2019.12 (arm-9.10)) 2.33.1.20191209
COMPILER_PATH=/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../libexec/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/:/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../libexec/gcc/:/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/:/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/:/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/lib/../lib64/:/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/lib/:/home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu/lib/:/home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'a.o' '-fPIC' '-I' '=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu' '-L=/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mlittle-endian' '-mabi=lp64'
 /home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../libexec/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/collect2 -plugin /home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../libexec/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../libexec/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc1mxz8m.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --sysroot=/home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu/ --eh-frame-hdr -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -X -EL -maarch64linux --fix-cortex-a53-843419 -o a.o /home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu/lib/crt1.o /home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu/lib/crti.o /home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/crtbegin.o -L=/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1 -L/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc -L/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/lib/../lib64 -L/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/lib -L/home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu/lib -L/home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu/usr/lib /tmp/ccVgrV4P.o -ldl -rpath-link /home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu//lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/crtend.o /home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu/lib/crtn.o
/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/ccVgrV4P.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x18): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu//lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.a(dlopen.o): in function `dlopen':
(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `__dlopen'
/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu//lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.a(dlclose.o): in function `dlclose':
(.text+0x0): undefined reference to `__dlclose'
/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu//lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.a(dlsym.o): in function `dlsym':
(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `__dlsym'
/home/dq/toolchain/gcc9/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/9.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/dq/sysroot/ubuntu//lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.a(dlerror.o): in function `dlerror':
(.text+0x0): undefined reference to `__dlerror'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

3. The error msg show that "__dlopen" is undefined which is referenced by libdl.a, so I dumped the glibc libs to find which lib contains this function and find out :
# readelf -s libc.a | grep dlopen
    30: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL HIDDEN   UND __libc_dlopen_mode
    11: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   HIDDEN   UND __dlopen
File: libc.a(sdlopen.o)
     5: 0000000000000000   160 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 dlopen_doit
    18: 00000000000000a0   140 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 __dlopen
    44: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL HIDDEN   UND __dlopen
    17: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL HIDDEN   UND __libc_dlopen_mode
    60: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL HIDDEN   UND __libc_dlopen_mode
     3: 0000000000000000    80 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 do_dlopen
    48: 00000000000004f8   144 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 __libc_dlopen_mode

the libc.a is located at ${SYSROOT}/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu, and the path is include using -rpath-link , and linker automaticly include option "-lc"
4
When dump the symbols of a.out generated in Test 1, and Test 2, there only contain dlopen@GLIBC_2.17:
    9: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dlopen@GLIBC_2.17 (2)
   103: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dlopen@@GLIBC_2.17

Test 4: Cross-compile on Host with sysroot
$ARMCC -o a.o  main.cpp -lc -ldl-2.31 -fPIC -Wl,-rpath-link,${SYSROOT}/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -I=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -L=/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --sysroot=${SYSROOT}

libdl.so on sysroot is a symlink to "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so", so I replace "-ldl" with "-ldl-2.31", and it succeed.
So. I think it is the linker cannot find the real lib that causes the problem
Question:

How the linker process symlink in sysroot? Will --sysroot affect the behavior of linker?
How can I config it right?

That is all I have found now , and I can't go any further now. Can anyone help ?Thanks !!

I'm only amateur and not familiar with linux, it is hard for me to anwser the question exactlly.
I made my sysroot by rsync command and used "symlinks -rc ~/sysroot" to correct the absolute path of the symlink. I found the "~/sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so" was linked to a absolute path to "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2". But "~/sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2" was linked to a relative path to "./libdl-2.31.so". So I guess there must be a mistake in one of the link. After I made "~/sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so" link to "./libdl.so.2", everything went well.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
